# Code 1001 on websocket connection for React Native application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, websocket

I have an application that is dependent on a websocket connection to render hundreds of components. I currently have the websocket stored in an useReducer hook to access it throughout my application once the user has been authenticated and in the main component that requires a websocket connection.
After about 3-5 minutes, I receive a websocket onclose (not onerror) event with 1001 code, which is either a server timeout/disconnection or when the client navigates away from the page/component.

I receive this code when I test with iOS Simulator and Expo Go on my physical iPhone device. I am not navigating away from the component.
Does anyone have any insight into why this is occurring? When testing the websocket on Postman, it seems to stay connected the entire time. So I suspect this is a FE issue, but I can't seem to find why the 1001 code event occurs, or why the websocket won't reconnect.

I have tried to implement a reconnect function and while it seems to reconnect, it doesn't re-render my components nor resume from the last connection:

```
const socket = new WebSocket(`http://url/ws?address=${walletAddress}&draftName=${draftId}`
    )

    const connectWS = () => {
        //initiate the websocket that is called from a utils file
        const ws = socket(walletAddress, draftId)
        //set the websocket in state (useReducer)
        context.setDraft({ type: DRAFT_ACTIONS.WEBSOCKET, payload: ws })

        ws.onopen = () => {
            //update websocket state status
            context.setDraft({ type: DRAFT_ACTIONS.SET_SOCKET, payload: SOCKET_STATUS.CONNECTED })
            console.log("Successfully connected!")
        }
        ws.onclose = (e) => {
            //update websocket state status, close websocket, and rerun function to reconnect
            console.log("Connection closed: ", e)
            context.setDraft({ type: DRAFT_ACTIONS.SET_SOCKET, payload: SOCKET_STATUS.NONE })
            ws.close()
            connectWS()
        }
        ws.onerror = (e) => {
            //update websocket state status when error occurs
            console.log("Client socket error: ", e)
            context.setDraft({ type: DRAFT_ACTIONS.SET_SOCKET, payload: SOCKET_STATUS.ERROR })
            ws.close()
        }

        ws.onmessage = (message) => {
            //...this section is working as expected
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        connectWS()
    }, [])
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).